# How many possible functions can there be from $X$ to $Y$?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

This was an optional question given by my lecturer:
Given that $|X| = n$ and $|Y| = m$, how many functions are there from $X$ to $Y$?

I know that a function must take in every value $x \in X$, giving out only one value $y = f(x) \in Y$.

Assume that $n<m$.

Then for each element in $X$, there are $m$ choices to pick from for the value.  So in total there would be $n^m$ choices to map $n$ elements from $X$ to the $m$ elements in $Y$.

Assume that $n>m$.
Then by similar reasoning, it will be $m^n$ choices.

If $m=n$ then the amount of ways is $n^n = m^m$.

Is this correct? If so is there a better way and if not, how would I have done this?

Comment: $m^n$ because $m$ times $m$ times $m$ $n$ times

Comment: In your case $n<m$ you meant to also have $m^{n}$, *not* $n^{m}$.  Think about the limiting case where $n=1$ and $m=2$.  There should be two maps in this case, not one.

Comment: @StephenPietromonaco I'm not seeing it; if $X = \{1,2\}$ and $Y = \{1\}$, then it seems that the only function would be if $f(1) = 1$ and $f(2) = 1$, meaning there's only one function which equals $1^2$. It seems that $m^n$ won't equal 1 here?  
Edit: I think I mixed myself up

Comment: @similarityinvariance1 Yes, the example you provide above is $n=2$ and $m=1$.  Therefore, you'd get $1^{2}=1$ map.  Consistent with your reasoning.  But as far as your proof, like people noted in the answers, there is no reason to have three cases.  You only need one case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each element in $X$, there are $m$ choices to pick from the total, hence in total, there are $$\overbrace{m \times \ldots \times m}^{n \text{ times}} = m^n.$$

The same argument works regardless of whether $m$ is bigger than $n$.

Answer (score 0):

n$^m$ as you indicated ; no need to have 3 cases , the reasoning is the same .Good job